# harbor - internal server issue - code 500 - after disk space resizing

Tags: docker, harbor

Since a diskspace issue on Harbor node, we increase it and restart the process but the GUI is not working properly for actions like replications, retention policy, CVE scanning

I checked the logs on server side :

```
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 ec2-user]# docker container ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                                                 NAMES
2abf5d05dab7        goharbor/nginx-photon:v1.9.3                             "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   0.0.0.0:4443->4443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8443/tcp   nginx
f33407aa2177        goharbor/harbor-jobservice:v1.9.3                        "/harbor/harbor_jobs…"   6 months ago        Up 7 weeks (healthy)                                                                          harbor-jobservice
6420cc8f84ab        goharbor/notary-server-photon:v0.6.1-v1.9.3              "/bin/sh -c 'migrate…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months                                                                                   notary-server
2546c8894905        goharbor/harbor-core:v1.9.3                              "/harbor/harbor_core"    6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)                                                                         harbor-core
c04e08177850        goharbor/clair-photon:v2.1.0-v1.9.3                      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   6060-6061/tcp                                                         clair
5e318f8c61d5        goharbor/notary-signer-photon:v0.6.1-v1.9.3              "/bin/sh -c 'migrate…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months                                                                                   notary-signer
2555d6e8ff9e        goharbor/chartmuseum-photon:v0.9.0-v1.9.3                "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   9999/tcp                                                              chartmuseum
599417cd4413        goharbor/harbor-registryctl:v1.9.3                       "/harbor/start.sh"       6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)                                                                         registryctl
8967774fa4f2        goharbor/redis-photon:v1.9.3                             "redis-server /etc/r…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   6379/tcp                                                              redis
c4181096df06        goharbor/registry-photon:v2.7.1-patch-2819-2553-v1.9.3   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   5000/tcp                                                              registry
28583420d59b        goharbor/harbor-db:v1.9.3                                "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   5432/tcp                                                              harbor-db
f06fa3ac558d        goharbor/harbor-portal:v1.9.3                            "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   8080/tcp                                                              harbor-portal
a358bc227c1c        goharbor/harbor-log:v1.9.3                               "/bin/sh -c /usr/loc…"   6 months ago        Up 6 months (healthy)   127.0.0.1:1514->10514/tcp                                             harbor-log

[root@ip-10-0-25-133 ec2-user]# docker logs harbor-log
rsyslogd: file '/var/log/docker/registry.log'[18] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: action 'action-0-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: file '/var/log/docker/registry.log'[18] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: action 'action-0-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: file '/var/log/docker/registry.log'[18] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: action 'action-0-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
```

There is an rsyslogd error related to harbor which I suppose blocked previous action on the GUI.

Trying to relaunch the containers via docker compose does not help, 2 containers stay on unhealthy status :

```
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 harbor]# docker-compose start
Starting log           ... done
Starting registry      ... done
Starting registryctl   ... done
Starting postgresql    ... done
Starting portal        ... done
Starting redis         ... done
Starting core          ... done
Starting jobservice    ... done
Starting proxy         ... done
Starting notary-signer ... done
Starting notary-server ... done
Starting clair         ... done
Starting chartmuseum   ... done
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 harbor]# docker container ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                                                                 NAMES
2abf5d05dab7        goharbor/nginx-photon:v1.9.3                             "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   7 months ago        Up 3 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:4443->4443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8443/tcp   nginx
f33407aa2177        goharbor/harbor-jobservice:v1.9.3                        "/harbor/harbor_jobs…"   7 months ago        Up 3 seconds (health: starting)                                                                         harbor-jobservice
6420cc8f84ab        goharbor/notary-server-photon:v0.6.1-v1.9.3              "/bin/sh -c 'migrate…"   7 months ago        Up 4 seconds                                                                                            notary-server
2546c8894905        goharbor/harbor-core:v1.9.3                              "/harbor/harbor_core"    7 months ago        Up 2 seconds (health: starting)                                                                         harbor-core
c04e08177850        goharbor/clair-photon:v2.1.0-v1.9.3                      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 months ago        Up 3 seconds (health: starting)   6060-6061/tcp                                                         clair
5e318f8c61d5        goharbor/notary-signer-photon:v0.6.1-v1.9.3              "/bin/sh -c 'migrate…"   7 months ago        Up 5 seconds                                                                                            notary-signer
2555d6e8ff9e        goharbor/chartmuseum-photon:v0.9.0-v1.9.3                "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 months ago        Up 8 seconds (health: starting)   9999/tcp                                                              chartmuseum
599417cd4413        goharbor/harbor-registryctl:v1.9.3                       "/harbor/start.sh"       7 months ago        Up 7 seconds (health: starting)                                                                         registryctl
8967774fa4f2        goharbor/redis-photon:v1.9.3                             "redis-server /etc/r…"   7 months ago        Up 7 seconds (health: starting)   6379/tcp                                                              redis
c4181096df06        goharbor/registry-photon:v2.7.1-patch-2819-2553-v1.9.3   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   7 months ago        Up 7 seconds (health: starting)   5000/tcp                                                              registry
28583420d59b        goharbor/harbor-db:v1.9.3                                "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 months ago        Up 7 seconds (health: starting)   5432/tcp                                                              harbor-db
f06fa3ac558d        goharbor/harbor-portal:v1.9.3                            "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   7 months ago        Up 7 seconds (health: starting)   8080/tcp                                                              harbor-portal
a358bc227c1c        goharbor/harbor-log:v1.9.3                               "/bin/sh -c /usr/loc…"   7 months ago        Up 9 seconds (health: starting)   127.0.0.1:1514->10514/tcp                                             harbor-log
```

The harbor logs are pointing again on a disk space issue :

```
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 harbor]# docker logs harbor-jobservice
Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 harbor]# docker logs clair
Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 harbor]# docker logs harbor-log
rsyslogd: file '/var/log/docker/registry.log'[18] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: action 'action-0-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: file '/var/log/docker/registry.log'[18] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: action 'action-0-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: file '/var/log/docker/registry.log'[18] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
rsyslogd: action 'action-0-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.1910.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
```

The disk space is not full on the docker host :

```
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 harbor]# df -ha
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
securityfs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           3.9G  383M  3.5G  10% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
bpf                0     0     0    - /sys/fs/bpf
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma
configfs           0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
/dev/xvda2      489G  383G  107G  79% /
selinuxfs          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/selinux
systemd-1          -     -     -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
hugetlbfs          0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
debugfs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
mqueue             0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
binfmt_misc        0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
tracefs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
tmpfs           782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/1000
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cac923a265f3adc2ba8a8b3f14a0fb21330db4a73562a484475cc782deb000fb/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/a358bc227c1cc3f986255adc03d354b773fb18f7a383182632b303e8977ddc0a/mounts/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/b0b97ca08f9a
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b8f287f1437be444902922a600eb4ae1fb83c9de1be9d439f9d36a08995ff544/merged
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6db8129dde48fcf90260c06d287e2e02db335dc80d097d8166b92ef0c1105e4e/merged
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/69d464cb11c9c12dd754190f734eaabbed2fe867e5cfa76d7812a068e0801602/merged
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2177176bd4c93cf12ff717aabe563c8469cf6bec426ca17e8d82df0618a3b0e/merged
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/11b8dd2688d07ad2a1b81fe11f235f7d3e648580c32c7757109d15fad8aa9030/merged
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8b0fe0a0b616f6d2343a919e62590b62b0bb714fbce4373936d5a3962d0cb12c/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/599417cd44133ac65ed8f084e1c645bf04b41548fc71cf150aa3e2ef224df7a8/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/2555d6e8ff9e3586a41f6f37fc66244d0b3496187da724787cfac175c7f999c4/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/f06fa3ac558da59cf8be1387b811e6d4e622d1ea49a4d97277eb68edf05e6388/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/8967774fa4f28c3df91ca40722dad81949b1d6c2fe60e3bbcf083cf325ebd7f2/mounts/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/a6281418be81
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/053f162aea2a
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/2c01de1d2aa5
shm              64M  4.0K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/28583420d59b3e4316b72f7a4d56d5ddf5fdf8c5932860f1f017d7b47ce2b0cf/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/c4181096df06edcddf3b2406556523ef26a47c7f441382bcd42446802cb708ec/mounts/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/19276a843cd7
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/8d1949d48460
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/85ba684c4adf
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/7faa4fa7c2fa7247d4f7a889f7d47ac97aa5002d83a03fc28bfa48e951e860ad/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/5e318f8c61d509346c688b4a3514597f571654620e4bd04dac536caaaa41ddf5/mounts/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/f8e546c2d757
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d93e3d145924701e719d7a5fd9e93531c36b46407052e14ec578ca887678f94d/merged
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/92736d5ae32243282bb26ebf9410f645388e5b8b1c1d498c369ad56282211dc6/merged
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/19653cd43524e1094144b7daaeb55b3305f688c1d64bd6eacdd899f2b7c57c38/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6420cc8f84ab45b145e6f142154c3ad3c09a3aa69455ded75fb33aab3415183c/mounts/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/c31bdc8081b5
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/f33407aa21776052609f2edaec1f0c637069992279cc9d19968f2e2d77b2d965/mounts/shm
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6f53a0994736d049eebd058f2f188e606acfa753e428e605a22943074eca7428/merged
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/02436d61c648
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/2abf5d05dab7d47f8fc528f78d112f7a0c3404d87b60649e897f349439e86c58/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/c04e081778502e8b8e0137512f6d9275daefa2d3641ce220f6d1f7e29a40b378/mounts/shm
overlay         489G  383G  107G  79% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/63e4dbe4d6213f6dcc1322f3691c7ff3244fb71e6562888b955d6bc4f93c74a4/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/2546c88949055855eef6967c63365b97e06ca38f46c781a336e2e6d7e67226bf/mounts/shm
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/9f232ba1bf77
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/1f50ca91cfa6
nsfs               0     0     0    - /run/docker/netns/2a0c5ac700e3
[root@ip-10-0-25-133 harbor]#
```

This does not help : https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/

Answer (score 1):

I was met with the same problem and the following commands solved it for me:

```
docker-compose down -v （if failed please reboot system）

docker-compose up -d
```